# Не перехватывается событие нажатия клавиши PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, keypress

Делаю приложение на *PyQt5*. У меня есть вот такое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу с помощью `keyPressEvent` перехватывать все нажатия клавиш в этом окне.
Большинство нажатий клавиш я перехватываю, но вот при нажатии стрелочек на нумпаде этот метод не работает, потому что это считается не за событие нажатия клавиши, а за какое-то другое событие, которое выделяет кнопку.

На картинке видно, что кнопка выделилась пунктиром:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кнопку удалить, то все клавиши перехватываются правильно.

Как можно обойти эту проблему и перехватывать все нажатия клавиш?

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(430, 130)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText('Нажмите на клавиатуре нужное вам сочетание клавиш')
        self.label.resize(400, 50)
        self.label.move(10, 10)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('Создать сочетание клавиш')
        self.button.resize(400, 50)
        self.button.move(10, 50)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print('press')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо за замечание, я добавил код.

Comment: а вот такую штуку не пробовали ? https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: @Интик ```PyQt5``` использовать в моём случае значительно удобнее, потому что мне в проекте нужно отслеживать именно события нажатий клавиш, поэтому хотелось бы найти способ именно с этой библиотекой. Но если не найду то да, буду keyboard использовать.

Comment: @Интик метод ```keyPressedEvent``` в коде это как раз событие из библиотеки ```PyQt5```.

Comment: @rew, а нумпад у вас включен? Если не включать, он не будет цифры вводить

Comment: @gil9red да нумпад работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> focusPolicy : Qt::FocusPolicy
>
> Это свойство определяет способ, которым виджет принимает фокус клавиатуры.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop

---

> void QWidget::setFocus()
>
> Передает фокус ввода с клавиатуры этому виджету (или его
> прокси-объекту фокуса), если этот виджет или один из его родителей
> является активным окном.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(430, 130)
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                         # !!!
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                              # !!!

        self.label = QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setText('Нажмите на клавиатуре нужное вам сочетание клавиш')
        self.label.resize(400, 50)
        self.label.move(10, 10)

        self.button = QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.button.setText('Создать сочетание клавиш')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked) 
        self.button.resize(400, 50)
        self.button.move(10, 50)
        self.button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)                        # !!!

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        print(f'press -> {key} -> {event.text()}')
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            print(f'Hello -> Key_Left')
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            print(f'Hello -> Key_Right')
        self.label.setText(f'Нажмите на клавиатуре нужное вам сочетание клавиш: {event.text()}')
        
    def onClicked(self):
        print('Click button')
        self.setFocus()                                                        # !!!


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]